# Optimising this simple jQuery script that vertically centers elements on pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

This is a simple jQuery script that I use to vertically center elements on pages. It's quite simple, but I would love to know if there is room for improvement.

```
(function( $ ){

    $.fn.flexVerticalCenter = function( onAttribute, verticalOffset, parentSelector ) {

        return this.each(function() {

            var $this           = $(this);                          // store the object
            var attribute       = onAttribute || 'margin-top';      // the attribute to put the calculated value on
            var offset          = parseInt(verticalOffset) || 0;    // the number of pixels to offset the vertical alignment by
            var parent_selector = parentSelector || null;           // a selector representing the parent to vertically center this element within

            // recalculate the distance to the top of the element to keep it centered
            var resizer = function () {
                var parent_height = (parent_selector) ? $this.parents(parent_selector).first().height() : $this.parent().height();

                $this.css(
                    attribute, ( ( ( parent_height - $this.height() ) / 2 ) + offset )
                );
            };

            // Call once to set.
            resizer();

            // Call on resize. Opera debounces their resize by default. 
            $(window).resize(resizer);

            // Apply a load event to images within the element so it fires again after an image is loaded
            $this.find('img').load(resizer);

        });
    };
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: This is well written code, I don't think you will find any improvements here, congrats :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put the header. It's not my script. It's from https://github.com/PaulSpr/jQuery-Flex-Vertical-Center. I just want to learn from it.

Comment: This is good code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments above, I think the code is ok :)